# PowerShell parameters for script task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm experimenting with PowerShell and having a little trouble understanding parameters.

I added

```
Param([string]$EmployeZip)
```

in the .ps1 file.

Also tried

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [System.String] $EmployeZip)
```

And I need to make it as an optional value so the user need not have to enter it.
I am trying to make a VSTS task using this powershell.The issue is, it is looking for the EmployeZip as a mandatory filed, instead of as an optional filed.
How can I make it as an optional filed?

Comment: Both of your examples define an optional parameter. If you run the script without parameters from CMD or PowerShell you will neither get an error nor will you be prompted to provide a value for the parameter. If it doesn't work for you the problem is most likely on the VSTS side.

Comment: Is there an error message? What does the the script logic do when `$EmployeeZip` is `$null`? Should you give `$EmployeeZip` a default value?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the quick responses.
I found it.

```
inputs": [
{
  "name": "EmployeZip",
  "type": "string",
  "label": "EmployeZip",
  "defaultValue": "",
  "required": false,
  "helpMarkDown": "I"
}
```

I have to make the  "required": false, in the task.json file. it was true.

Comment: since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer.